# Divide data into bins with inf Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, intervals

I'm having a problem with qcut function in python. My upper bounds and lower bounds are -Inf and Inf, but when I apply qcut with these bounds, Python return this error "cannot convert float infinity to integer".

My friends told me that I should change the Inf into 1e100 (a very large number represents ) so qcut could use. However, another error occur: "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Example:

```py
a1 = [-Inf, 26.6, 36.2, 38.7, 42.1, 47.2, 117.7] 
a2 = [-1e100, 26.6, 36.2, 38.7, 42.1, 47.2, 117.7]

cut_range = [-Inf, 27.0, 33.0, 40.0, Inf] #For a1

cut_range = [-1e+100, 27.0, 33.0, 40.0, 1e+100] #For a2

b = pd.qcut(a, cut_range, duplicates = 'drop')
```

I want to have a final result like this:

```py
b = ['[-Inf,27]','(33,40]','(33,40],'(40, Inf]','(40, Inf]','(40, Inf]']
or with 1e100:
b = ['[-1e100,27]','(33,40]','(33,40],'(40, 1e100]','(40, 1e100]','(40, 1e100]']
```

And someone could help me to explained how Inf works in Python and in R. They are both Infinite but how are they behave so different.

In R I tried function with Inf and it worked:

```
as.character(cut(a1,cut_range, include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Comment: `qcut` is for quantiling.  If you already have cut points you probably want `pd.cut`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html). It's because you're binning/labeling your data based on ranges:

```
a1 = [-np.inf, 26.6, 36.2, 38.7, 42.1, 47.2, 117.7] 
cut_range = [-np.inf, 27.0, 33.0, 40.0, np.inf]
pd.cut(a1, bins = cut_range, include_lowest=True)
>> [(-inf, 27.0], (-inf, 27.0], (33.0, 40.0], (33.0, 40.0], (40.0, inf], (40.0, inf], (40.0, inf]]
```

Also note that qcut labels data based on `quantiles`, so if you have `[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]` as your `cut_range` then the data will be divided into 4 quantiles. The first quantile will belong to values from the minimum to the 25th percentile(0-0.25). When you add in -np.inf, there can't be a negative percentile value, and hence you got the error.

Comment: Ah, so that's the problem with -np.inf, so 1e100 is not necessary in this case, right? Btw thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

#### `searchsorted`

Even though I commented that you need `pd.cut`.  I personally use `searchsorted`.

```
a = np.array([-np.inf, 26.6, 36.2, 38.7, 42.1, 47.2, 117.7])
cut = np.array([27.0, 33.0, 40.0])

labels = np.array([
    f"({x:.1f}, {y:.1f}]"
    for x, y in zip([-np.inf] + list(cut), list(cut) + [np.inf])
])

labels[cut.searchsorted(a)]

array(['(-inf, 27.0]', '(-inf, 27.0]', '(33.0, 40.0]', '(33.0, 40.0]',
       '(40.0, inf]', '(40.0, inf]', '(40.0, inf]'], dtype='<U12')
```

The result is either an array of codes `cut.searchsorted(a)` or of labels as I've shown above.  It could be tortured into a `pandas.Categorical` type but then you really should just use `pd.cut`.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I don't know searchsorted() function could do that. And for the Categorical, I think it took me several hours just to convert it into list type  -_-